# How to override the id's annotation in a Doctrine inheritnce hiearchy

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm

I'm working with ***Symfony*** and ***MySQL*** and I'm trying to follow some convention across all my table, one of them is to keep each id's colmun name in the format `id_tablename` (see [diagram](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YIQ6T.png)). So i kept the `id` name generated by Symfony in the classes, but I want to replace each field in the database by `id_product`, `id_tire`, etc, ...

For that i'm using the ***Column*** annotation, e.g:

```
abstract class Product
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer", name="id_product")
     */
    private $id;

    // ...
}
```

And for each child class, I use ***AttributeOverride*** annotation [as explained in the doc](https://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/2.7/tutorials/override-field-association-mappings-in-subclasses.html), like bellow

```
/**
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass=TireRepository::class)
 * @ORM\AttributeOverrides(
 *     @ORM\AttributeOverride(
 *         name = "id",
 *         column=@ORM\Column(name="id_tire")
 *     )
 * )
 */
class Tire extends Product
{
    // ...
}
```

But when attempting a `php bin/console make:migration` I got the error **`The column type of attribute 'id' on class 'App\Entity\Tire' could not be changed.`**

Did I miss something ?

**Edit**: I tried to override another attribute (`$name`) with the following code that work:

```php
/**
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass=RimRepository::class)
 * @ORM\AttributeOverrides(
 *     @ORM\AttributeOverride(
 *         name = "name",
 *         column=@ORM\Column(name="name_rim")
 *     )
 * )
 */
class Rim extends Product
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=255)
     */
    private $name;

    // ...
}
```

But even by doing the same thing with `$id` attribute, I still have the same error message.

Seem like Doctrine have difficult to work with renamed fields too, when you have relations betweens classes. So for now I keep the default `id` name for each table in database, to continue working.

Comment: It's complaining about the type.  Just a guess but maybe add type="integer" just to see what happens.  Probably just get a different error message but maybe not.

Comment: I tried with `type="integer"` but still have the same error. Also Itried

Comment: I like to impose a bit of uniformity in my Doctrine mappings.  Hard to do with annotations.  Reading your link about AttributesOverrides makes my head spin.  I think there is a Doctrine slack channel you might try. In any event, I use [PHP doctrine mappings](https://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/2.7/reference/php-mapping.html).   Makes this sort of thing easy.  But I have yet to encounter anyone else who uses it as well.

Comment: I did'nt knew you can do mapping in this way as most docs/example I found use mapping inside comments, I'll gie it a try

My last response was truncated, I was saying I tried to override another attribute inherited, and it's working well. But not when overriding **id**. (I add exemple of what worked in the question above)

Answer (score 1):

Please check correct example below.
Looks like you just missing `type="integer"` in `AttributeOverride`

```
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

/**
 * @MappedSuperclass
 */
abstract class Product
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer", name="id_product")
     */
    protected $id;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=255)
     */
    protected $name;

    // ...
}
```

```
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

/**
 * @ORM\Entity
 * @ORM\AttributeOverrides(
 *     @ORM\AttributeOverride(
 *         name = "id",
 *         column=@ORM\Column(name="id_tire", type="integer")
 *     )
 * )
 */
class Tire extends Product
{
    // ...
}
```

As result migration SQL will be similar to following

```
$this->addSql('CREATE TABLE tire (id_tire INT NOT NULL, name VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL, PRIMARY KEY(id_tire))');
```

Comment: I tried that as well, but i had this error about foreign keys: shell  
```An exception occurred while executing 'ALTER TABLE picture ADD CONSTRAINT FK_16DB4F894584665A FOREIGN KEY (product_id) REFERENCES product (id)': SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 3734 Failed to add the foreign key constraint. Missing column 'id' for constraint 'FK_16DB4F894584665A' in the referenced table 'product'
```

That was because I had relations to others table in childs entities, and those entites excpect a column named **`id`** I think. But I retried just now and it's working if I remove those relations

Comment: Looks like that your database/entities structure more complex than you specify in original question. You could try to simplify new issue and create new well-described question. It's impossible to help you with current inputs.

Comment: I answered bellow with what i did, and it's seem like doctrine still looking for `id` column when working with foreign keys. It's producing this request `$this->addSql('ALTER TABLE picture ADD CONSTRAINT FK_16DB4F894584665A FOREIGN KEY (product_id) REFERENCES product (id)');`

Comment: Could you provide Picture class, please? Without it it's impossible to found root cause by community.

Comment: Moreover it's good practice to create new question, because now hierarchy is broken.
https://stackoverflow.com/a/64820561/3178453 contains answer to original question (answer is same with https://stackoverflow.com/a/64800744/3178453), and it contains questions "How to handle another relationship `picture` correctly?"

Comment: Ak I see, sorry about that. I'll do new question as soon as possible with more details, because I made many change in my working files since and I have to finish it next week

Comment: this solution worked for me, tested on a non-id field!

Answer (score 0):

It seem like it's a problem with how Doctrine works. As my system require many relations between entities, I didn't noticed it, but without relations, evrything works fine if they are correctly mapped. For exemple with:

- Parent class

```php
/**
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass=ProductRepository::class)
 */
class Product
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer", name="id_product")
     */
    private $id;

    // ...
}
```

- Child classes

```php
/**
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass=RimRepository::class)
 * @ORM\AttributeOverrides(
 *     @ORM\AttributeOverride(
 *         name = "id",
 *         column=@ORM\Column(type="integer", name="id_rim")
 *     )
 * )
 */
class Rim extends Product
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     */
    private $id;

    // ...
}
```

```php
/**
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass=TIreRepository::class)
 * @ORM\AttributeOverrides(
 *     @ORM\AttributeOverride(
 *         name = "id",
 *         column=@ORM\Column(type="integer", name="id_tire")
 *     )
 * )
 */
class Tire extends Product
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     */
    private $id;

    // ...
}
```

Will generate those [tables](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2xWp1.png) in database. But with relations at any level of the hiearchy like [in this case](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tTWCl.png), Doctrine will fail to retrive renamed column with annotations. Si in my case I had to keep the default `id` name across all tables in order to let Doctrine find what he excpect when making relations between tables.

I tried to remove all relation from child class and keep those from parent class, also the opposite, but Doctrine alwas still searching column `id` while looking for relation/contraints:

```php
$this->addSql('ALTER TABLE picture ADD CONSTRAINT FK_16DB4F894584665A FOREIGN KEY (product_id) REFERENCES product (id)');
```

It's seem like impossible to do right now, with complex database structure.